# Jenkins Credentials String Interpolation

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, credentials

I have a Jenkins pipeline which uses credentials to authenticate a `GET` request from a website. I would like to prevent the sensitive environment variables from being leaked by Groovy string interpolation.

Complying with the suggestion from the Jenkins [User Handbook](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables), the `Jenkinsfile` would be:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        EXAMPLE_CREDS = credentials('example-credentials-id')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh('curl -u $EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR:$EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW https://example.com/')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works in the case that the URL is fixed but, I would like my URL to include variables (see `${EXTENSION}` in the snippet below).

```
    environment {
        EXAMPLE_CREDS = credentials('example-credentials-id')
        EXTENSION     = 'url/extended/'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh('curl -u $EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR:$EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW https://example.com/${EXTENSION}')
            }
        }
```

The issue is that the Groovy interpreter does not replace `${EXTENSION}` with `url/extended/` at runtime. The output in the Jenkins log is:

`+ curl -u ****:**** https://example.com/${EXTENSION}`

I tried replacing the credential environment variable with a [withCredentials](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#for-other-credential-types) block and swapping the apostrophes surrounding the command with quotation marks,

```
    environment {
        EXTENSION     = 'url/extended/'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "example-credentials-id", passwordVariable: "EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW ", usernameVariable: "EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR")]) {
                steps {
                sh("curl -u $EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR:$EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW https://example.com/${EXTENSION}")
            }
        }
```

which functionally works but, the following warning is reported:

```
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR, EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW, example-credentials-id]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ curl -u ****:**** https://example.com/url/extended/
```

My work around was to write a SH script which Jenkins calls. Jenkins would pass the credentials in as input arguments and the script would handle the variable substitution.

```
    environment {
        EXAMPLE_CREDS = credentials('example-credentials-id')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh('bash script.sh $EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR $EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW')
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to keep accomplish this *feat* within Jenkins or is outsourcing it the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

See the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64834714/groovy-string-interpolation-in-jenkins-pipeline-mixing-credentials-and-constan) posted by Stephan Wright. The solution involves using quotes and escaping the `$` before the credentials. The two possible solutions are

```
    environment {
        EXAMPLE_CREDS = credentials('example-credentials-id')
        EXTENSION     = 'url/extended/'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh("curl -u \$EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR:\$EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW https://example.com/${EXTENSION}")
            }
        }
```

or

```
    environment {
        EXTENSION     = 'url/extended/'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "example-credentials-id", passwordVariable: "EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW ", usernameVariable: "EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR")]) {
                steps {
                sh("curl -u \$EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR:\$EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW https://example.com/${EXTENSION}")
            }
        }
```

My preference is the first solution, in favor of keeping a 'flatter' pipeline.